# Scraping author names from a website with try/except using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, try-except

I am trying to use Try/Except in order to scrape through different pages of a URL containing author data. I need a set of author names from 10 subsequent pages of this website.

```
# Import Packages
import requests
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
# Output list
authors = [] 
# Website Main Page URL
URL = 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/'
res = requests.get(URL)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
# Get the contents from the first page
for item in soup.select(".author"):
    authors.append(item.text)
page = 1
pagesearch = True
# Get the contents from 2-10 pages
while pagesearch:
    # Check if page is available
    try:
            req = requests.get(URL + '/' + 'page/' + str(page) + '/')
            soup = bs(req.text, 'html.parser')
            page = page + 1
            for item in soup.select(".author"): # Append the author class from the webpage html
                authors.append(item.text)  
    except:
        print("Page not found")
        pagesearch == False
        break # Break if no page is remaining

print(set(authors)) # Print the output as a unique set of author names
```

First page doesn't have any page number in it's URL so I treated it separately. I'm using the try/except block for iterating through all of the possible pages and throw an exception and break the loop when the last page is scanned.

When I run the program, it enters to an infinite loop while it needs to print the "Page not found" message when the pages are over. When I interrupt the kernel, I see the correct result as a list and my exception statement but nothing before that. I get the following result.

```
Page not found
{'Allen Saunders', 'J.K. Rowling', 'Pablo Neruda', 'J.R.R. Tolkien', 'Harper Lee', 'J.M. Barrie', 
 'Thomas A. Edison', 'J.D. Salinger', 'Jorge Luis Borges', 'Haruki Murakami', 'Dr. Seuss', 'George 
  Carlin', 'Alexandre Dumas fils', 'Terry Pratchett', 'C.S. Lewis', 'Ralph Waldo Emerson', 'Jim 
  Henson', 'Suzanne Collins', 'Jane Austen', 'E.E. Cummings', 'Jimi Hendrix', 'Khaled Hosseini', 
 'George Eliot', 'Eleanor Roosevelt', 'André Gide', 'Stephenie Meyer', 'Ayn Rand', 'Friedrich 
  Nietzsche', 'Mother Teresa', 'James Baldwin', 'W.C. Fields', "Madeleine L'Engle", 'William 
  Nicholson', 'George R.R. Martin', 'Marilyn Monroe', 'Albert Einstein', 'George Bernard Shaw', 
 'Ernest Hemingway', 'Steve Martin', 'Martin Luther King Jr.', 'Helen Keller', 'Charles M. Schulz', 
 'Charles Bukowski', 'Alfred Tennyson', 'John Lennon', 'Garrison Keillor', 'Bob Marley', 'Mark 
  Twain', 'Elie Wiesel', 'Douglas Adams'}
```

What can be the reason for this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's because there is a page literally. The exception may arise when there is no page to show on the browser.
But when you make a request for this one:

```
http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/11/
```

Then, the browser shows a page that bs4 still can parse to get an element.

How to stop at page 11? You can trace the presence of the Next Page Button.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Yes, this can be a good approach to follow. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the built-in [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) function to go from pages 1-10 instead:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/{}/"
authors = []

for page in range(1, 11):
    response = requests.get(url.format(page))
    print("Requesting Page: {}".format(response.url))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    for tag in soup.select(".author"):
        authors.append(tag.text)

print(set(authors))
```

Comment: Yes, this approach will work however, I'm looking for a solution which also fits for possible changes in a website. Thanks for your answer.